# Is there such a phrase as "or else"?

Tags: word-usage, expression-choice, phrase-usage

I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not very sure. For example:

> She thought her boyfriend had settled with someone in the island, **or else**
>   his plane had crashed in the middle of the Pacific ocean.

Or maybe I was thinking of something similar?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the OP isn't *only* asking if "or else" exists but whether he used it correctly in his example sentence AND if he was perhaps thinking of a similar expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are a few alternatives:

- alternatively,
- otherwise,
- if not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Does the phrase "or else" exist?

Comment: @JanoChen - Yes, it does exist. The way it is used in your query sentence is legitimate: the woman is holding two different possibilities in mind regarding what happened to her boyfriend.

Answer (score 1):

"Or else" is also used as a short-hand threat without actually stating what you are threatening to do.

"Put the cookie down, or else."

To me this reads better...

"She thought her boyfriend had settled with someone in the island, or **that** his plane had crashed in the middle of the Pacific ocean."

or

"He must have settled down with someone in the island, or else his plane crashed..."

Comment: That is ONE of the meanings of the expression, but it is irrelevant to the question posed. The one that is relevant here is as stated by Josh61.

Comment: I was answering the question "Does the phrase or else exist?"

Comment: This was better before the edit, it showed a use of _or else_ proving that the 'phrase' does exist. The edit has confused matters as there is nothing wrong with the _or else_ in the **example** provided by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's sentence is perfectly acceptable but I believe he had *either that, or* in mind. It is in any case the more idiomatic expression for describing a scenario with only two possible interpretations.

> *She thought her boyfriend had settled with someone in the island—**either that, or** his plane had crashed in the middle of the Pacific ocean.*

Note I used a comma before the conjunction *or* but it's not obligatory.

The author of [Killer Focus](http://books.google.it/books?id=uCjappY-RDQC&pg=PT144&dq=%22either%20that,%20or%22%20he%20had&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Zop0U4eYHseM7AbG-IGQCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22either%20that,%20or%22%20&f=false) uses "either that, or" four times in her novel, once with the dash punctuation (thank you @Janus Bahs for the edit)